# Text disappears after reaching the required length

Tags: css, reactjs

i've tried to write a function that returns a JSX expression which rescales the font-size if it reaches a certain length to fit in the container div.

I've made a condition in it that watches if 1) the text exists and 2) if it exceeded the length I wanted. Here is the function:

```
scaledName() {
  if (this.state.name && this.state.name.length <= 11) {
    return   (
      <div className="name-preview">{this.state.name}</div>
    );
  } else if (this.state.name && this.state.name.length > 11) {
    var length = this.state.name.length;
    var fontScale = 203 - (length - 11);
    var stringPercent = fontScale.toString() + '%';
    return (
      <div className="name-preview" style={{ fontSize: stringPercent }}>{
          this.state.name,
          console.log(stringPercent, 'font-size'),
          console.log(this.state.name, 'Név')
        }</div>
```

See if `this.state.name.length` exceeds 11, for every new character I want the font-size to be decreased by 1%.

The console logs both the `stringPercent` and the `this.state.name variables, all works fine except if the string's length exceeds 11, the whole string disappears.

In the CSS file here is the class:

```
.name-preview {
  position: absolute;
  top: 11.5rem;
  left: 34.5rem;
  right: 40rem;
  color: #000000;
  font-size: 203%;
  font-weight: bold;
  width: 13rem;
  text-align: center;
}
```

Comment: Any errors in the console? Does it work if you remove the comma expression from the `<div>` value? See answer below for some method cleanup; it's much simpler than you appear to be making it.

Comment: No errors shown in the console but your clean-up made it work! Thanks man, i'm pretty new to this language:)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

(This is not an answer, it's just a cleaned-up method, because it was driving me nuts.)

```
scaledName() {
  const { name } = this.state;

  if (!name) {
    return null;
  }

  if (name.length <= 11) {
    return (
      <div className="name-preview">{name}</div>
    );
  }

  const fontScale = 214 - name.length;
  return (
    <div className="name-preview" style={{ fontSize: `${fontScale}%` }}>
      {name}
    </div>    
  );
}
```

I'd actually probably move this into a slightly-smarter-but-light component. This is *completely* untested, but gives a rough idea:

```
import { isEmpty } from 'lodash'; // Or whatever.

const ScaledName = ({ value, startingScale=203, scaleAtLength=11, scaleFactor=1 }) => {
  if (isEmpty(value)) {
    return null;
  }

  const styles = {};

  if (value.length > scaleAtLength) {
    const scaleDelta = (value.length - scaleAtLength) * scaleFactor;
    const fontScale = startingScale - scaleDelta;

    styles.fontSize = `${fontScale}%`;
  }

  return (
    <div className="name-preview" style={styles}>
      {value}
    </div>
  );
};
```